# Como recolher teclado quando botão cancelar busca é clicado?

Tags: ios, objective-c, teclado, uisearchbar

Como recolher o teclado quando o botão de cancelar é clicado em um UISearchBar?

Tentei alguns métodos e até os métodos do delegate, mas não funcionou.

Irei colocar uma imagem para ser mais preciso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso que quando o botão de cancelar (botão com o X) for clicado/selecionado ele recolha o teclado.

Comment: Você pode até conseguir fazer isso, mas essa não é a função desse botão. O botão com **X** é para limpar o texto digitado. Seria melhor você usa o próprio botão de cancelar que `UISearchBar` disponibiliza: `searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;`

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento. Pensei ter visto essa funcao em algum outro app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa o delegate do searchBar para adicionar o botao cancelar quando o utilizador começar a introduzir texto:

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    [_seachBar resignFirstResponder];
}
-(void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    _seachBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
}
-(void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    _seachBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
}
```

Comment: Vou tentar e ver como fica. Ja trago o resultado :D

Comment: Realmente funcionou!

Comment: @TiagoAmaral não percebi proposito do teu comentário

Comment: Nada com vc não @dasilva ... é que não sei como entrar em contato direto com um administrador. Pensei que marcando ele no comentário ele poderia ver e responder.